# How to Convert a .MPG to .FLV using PHP on Azure Platform

Tags: php, azure, flv

How we can Convert a MPG to FLV using PHP on Azure Platform?can you gave me a good tutorial links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 - install ffmpeg, see this thread http://groups.google.com/group/ffmpeg-php-windows/browse_thread/thread/611894c7a6a17729

Step 2 - converting process itself, see this http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

This will help you understand ffmpeg-php class http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php

Comment: @will this work in AZure Platform?

Comment: php & php extension should work without any problems. The conversion requires to call the converter and file operations, this requires some research...